# Using pg.key.get_pressed() to press keys, command repeats multiple times for one press

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a sudoku GUI where the user enters the starting numbers and when the user hits enter, it solves the board. I made a command that when the user clicks on a block, it gives it a red outline and then they can enter a number between 1 and 9. I want the user to be able to go to the next block by pressing an arrow **once** and going to the next block, however, using pg.K_UP etc. makes the GUI skip a couple of blocks (I have to press an arrow very fast to make it move by one block only). How can I fix this? Here is my code

```
            # click on a block
            for x in range(9):
                for y in range(9):
                    # give the block a colored outline
                    if pg.mouse.get_pressed() == (1, 0, 0) and \
                            x * xmax / 9 < pg.mouse.get_pos()[0] < (x + 1) * xmax / 9 and y * ymax / 9 < \
                            pg.mouse.get_pos()[1] < (y + 1) * ymax / 9:
                        xpos = x
                        ypos = y
                        clicked = True
            if clicked:
                pg.draw.rect(scr, red, (xpos * xmax/9, ypos * ymax/9, xmax/9, ymax/9), 4)

            # Move to the next block
            if keys[pg.K_UP]:
                ypos -= 1
            if keys[pg.K_DOWN]:
                ypos += 1
            if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
                xpos -= 1
            if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
                xpos += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needs to use the keyboard events for UP/DOWN.  The event loop will receive a single event when the key is first depressed (`pygame.KEYDOWN`), and then another event when it is released (`pygame.KEYUP`).  Along with the event, is the `.key` member variable.  The code can check this to see which key the event was generated by.

```
# Inside main loop
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
        done = True
    elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN ):
        # TODO: paste in mouse-click code
        pass
    elif ( event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN ):
        # Which key was pressed 
        if ( event.key == pygame.K_UP ):
            y_pos -= 1
        elif ( event.key == pygame.K_DOWN ):
            y_pos += 1
        elif ( event.key == pygame.K_LEFT ):
            x_pos -= 1
        elif ( event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT ):
            x_pos += 1
```